# Combining ES6 unicode literals with ES6 template literals

Tags: javascript, unicode, ecmascript-6, unicode-escapes, template-literals

If I want to print a unicode Chinese character in ES6/ES2015 javascript, I can do this:

```
console.log(`\u{4eb0}`);
```

Likewise, if I want to interpolate a variable into a template string literal, I can do this:

```
let x = "48b0";
console.log(`The character code is ${ x.toUpperCase() }.`);
```

However, it seems that I can't combine the two to print a list of, for example, 40 consecutive unicode Chinese characters. This doesn't work:

```
for (let i = 0, firstCharCode = parseInt("4eb0", 16); i < 40; ++i) {
    let hexCharCode = (firstCharCode + i).toString(16);
    console.log(`\u{${ hexCharCode }}`); // generates SyntaxError
}
```

So I'm asking if there's any way it's possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need to use [`String.fromCodePoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint), which accepts a number and returns a character.

You can't do it with literals because... well... it's not a literal anymore. Literals can't be produced as the result of a procedure, they need to be written as literals.

Comment: Worth mentioning that if your character is more than a single code point then you _can_ to pass them separated by commas which you would separate with a `\u` in a real literal. So "\uD834\uDF06" becomes `String.fromCodePoint(0xD834, 0xDF06)` but unlike literals you don't have to since `String.fromCodePoint(0x1D306)` would also work where `"\u1D306"` obviously doesn't.