# How can I render unicode in javascript using a variable?

Tags: javascript, unicode, emoji, unicode-escapes

It works when I just use a string directly, but not with a variable.

### Works

```js
console.log(`\u{1F436}`);
```

### Doesn't Work

```js
const unicode = '1F436';

console.log(`\u{ ${unicode} }`);
```

I get this error:

> Parsing error: Invalid escape sequence in template

What am I missing? How can I properly escape this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining ES6 unicode literals with ES6 template literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155412/combining-es6-unicode-literals-with-es6-template-literals)

Answer (score 4):

`\u` can only be used as part of a Unicode literal that's present in the source code. It can't be built up through interpolation.

If you want to reference a Unicode codepoint by value, use `String.fromCodePoint()`:

```js
var c = 0x1f436;
// or if you wanted to start with a string: c = parseInt("1F436", 16)

console.log(String.fromCodePoint(c));
```

Comment: So in OP's case `String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(unicode, 16))`?

Comment: Sure, or however else you wanted to build up that value.

Comment: @EmileBergeron This worked with your tip, so thank you. You can use `let unicode = '1F436'; unicode = parseInt(unicode, 16); unicode = String.fromCodePoint(unicode);` and then `console.log(unicode);`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because `\u` expects a hexadecimal digit after it but you're passing a string. I'm guessing it has to do with how React is parsing it because I'm getting an error as well. But there is a solution:

```
// Option 1 - Use template literals:
<p>{`\u1F436`}</p>

// Option 2 - pass the full unicode as the variable and output that variable:
const unicode = "\u1F436"
<p>{unicode}</p>
```

Comment: This is not addressing the question.